# django all-auth case insensitive username

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-allauth, django-users

I'm using [Django AllAuth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) and was making a simple profile page for the users of the app. That is reachable by typing in a user's username.

```
# urls.py
path('<str:username>/', UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),

# views.py
class UserDetail (DetailView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/user.html'
    model = User

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

My thought is that it would work like twitter out of the gate. A user creates an account username like `MyUsername` which looks nice case-sensitive and is searchable case-insensitive. So if someone searched a user they could type in the username case-insensitive and it would always pull up the right user just with the nicer looking case-sensitive style.

That's when I realized a user with username: `MyUsername` as supposed to `myusername` is actually 2 different users! Naive for me to think otherwise I suppose.

---

Django AllAuth does have `ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING (=True)` that I could implement but that would just make it so all usernames are lowercase while I was looking to just make usernames case-insensitive unique while still showing the nicer case-sensitive version.

What would be the best approach to handle make the username case-insensitive unique but still show the case-sensitive format to the users?

Comment: You can ovverride `LoginForm` and `login` method in it to check username case insensitive. You also need to override `SignupForm` to check that there is no user with same username(case insensitive) You can read it here - [link](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING = False` and keep a "displayable" version of username in separate field (set on signup). If a username is changed, both names should be then updated as well (one internal for auth handling, the other for displaying).